# What is the best way to detect whether the objects are saved in javafx desktop application?

Tags: java, javafx

I am currently developing a javafx desktop application. It contains two `observableList<Item>`s and two `HashMap<String,Double>`s. I am currently develop the `menuBar` , which contains these `menuItem` s, i.e. `Open`, `New`, `Save` and `Save As`.

Consider the case where I have started the desktop application and added a few `Item` to the `observableList<Item>`. Then all of a sudden, I want to hit any one of the `menuItem`s listed above. First thing I want to check in my program is **whether the current workflow needs to be saved** before proceeding to start a new workflow (New menuitem).

I have the following method in place at the moment but I think it looks very clumsy and inefficient. 
The method I developed is to set a variable `private static final boolean isSaved = false;`

And then within the two observableLists, I added a Listener to them:

```
    obslist1.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Item>(){
          @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
                isSaved = false;
          }
    });
```

The code for `obslist2` is identical. And the `isSaved` variable is set to `true` only if the user actually presses the `Save` or `Save As` menuItem.

I find my method very clumsy and inefficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
BooleanProperty saved = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
InvalidationListener savedListener = obs -> saved.set(false);
```

and then

```
private void save() {
    // save the data...

    // mark data as saved:
    saved.set(true);
}
```

with

```
obslist1.addListener(savedListener);
obslist2.addListener(savedListener);

anythingElseThatMightChangeAndIsImportant.addListener(savedListener);
```

Your save button and menu item, etc can do

```
saveButton.disableProperty().bind(saved);
```

Comment: Thing is I already added a listener to my observable list to fire off a separate event whenever there is any change to the observable list. So, how could I add your `savedListener` to the list ?

Comment: I don't understand your question

Comment: Sorry. Is it possible to add multiple listeners to an observable list? And how?

Comment: Right. I thought the new listener would always override the previous listener that is why I asked this stupid question.

Comment: In that case the method would have been called `setListener`, not `addListener`.

Comment: Sorry. I am a bit slow here. What is the purpose of `menuItem.disableProperty().bind(saved);` here? Why are we using it? Does it mean the `menuITem` is disabled when `saved` is `true` ?

Comment: Yes, it means the menu item is disabled when saved is true. Have you considered just trying things, or maybe reading the documentation, instead of posting every single little question you have on here?

Comment: Yes. I did that. I read the documentation and ran the code before asking the questions. I am just worried that I still might not have fully understood the concepts. I was trying to be thorough and made sure I was not just copying and pasting things.